# results from both tables even corresponding rows does not exist in other table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I would like to get the results from both tables even corresponding rows does not exist in each other table. Which join I should use to get the results like below. I tried FULL, but no luck.

Table 1:

```
CA  CB  CC
=== === ===
AA  11  X1
BB  22  X2
CC  33  X3
EE  44  X4
```

Table 2:

```
CA  CB  CD
=== === ===
AA  11  Y1
BB  22  Y2
FF  55  Y5
GG  66  Y6
```

expecting Results like:

```
CA  CB  CC      CD
=== === ===     ===
AA  11  X1      Y1
BB  22  X2      Y2
CC  33  X3      (null)
EE  44  X4      (null)
FF  55  (null)  Y5
GG  66  (null)  Y6
```

Comment: Re: "I tried FULL, but no luck": You do indeed need to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Why not post the query you tried?

Comment: When you say you've tried "FULL" are you talking about a full outer join or something else? Can you supply a copy the SQL statement you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   COALESCE (t1.CA, t2.CA) CA
  ,COALESCE (t1.CB, t2.CB) CB
  ,CC
  ,CD
FROM Table1 t1
FULL JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.CA = t2.CA AND t1.CB = t2.CB
ORDER BY 
   COALESCE (t1.CA, t2.CA) 
  ,COALESCE (t1.CB, t2.CB)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ece1/4)